# How do I send the output of my first operation into the input of the second?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to find a way to send the output of `crop_rows` called at the very bottom into the input of `delete_Apps` called directly after, but I'm unsure as to what to feed it. Also, do I need to remove:

```
file_obj.close()
```

from the `crop_rows` function so that my script continues to run through both functions?

```
import os, csv, sys, Tkinter, tkFileDialog as fd


# stop tinker shell from opening as only needed for file dialog

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()


#crop_rows deletes the extra info automatically generated in the Waders report 

def crop_rows(in_path):
    # read file into memory
    file_obj = open(in_path, 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter='\t')
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        if not row or not any(row):
            break #stop at empty row
        else:
            data.append(row)
    file_obj.close()

    print 'Found', len(data), 'rows of data without empty lines.'
    conf = raw_input('delete remaining lines? (Y|N): ').upper()[0]

    if conf == 'Y':
        # write data to file
        file_obj = open(in_path, 'wb')
        writer = csv.writer(file_obj)
        writer.writerows(data)
        file_obj.close



#delete_Apps deletes and leads that are currently Applicants in gHire as their Status

def delete_Apps(in_path):
    # read file into memory
    file_obj = open(in_path, 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter='\t')
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        if 'Applicant' not in row:
            data.append(row)
    file_obj.close()

    print 'Found', len(data), 'Leads with Applicant in gHire as Status.'
    conf = raw_input('delete these leads? (Y|N): ').upper()[0]

    if conf == 'Y':
        # write data to file
        file_obj = open(in_path, 'wb')
        writer = csv.writer(file_obj)
        writer.writerows(data)
        file_obj.close


def main():
    in_path = None
    prog_name = sys.argv[0]

    # check if in_path are inlcuded as cmd line args...
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        in_path = sys.argv[1]
        if not os.path.exists(in_path):
            print 'Usage:', prog_name, '[file_path>]'
            print 'cannot find the file provided for file_path:\n', in_path
            sys.exit("Error - invalid excel_file_path arg")
    else:
        try:
            # set current working directory to user's my documents folder
            os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getenv('userprofile'),'documents'))
        except:
            pass

    # ask user for path to file...
    while not in_path:
        print "Please select the file to read data from ..."
        try:
            in_path = fd.askopenfilename()
        except:
            print 'Error selecting file.'
        if not in_path:
            cont = raw_input('Do you want to continue? (Y|N): ').upper()[0]
            if cont == 'N':
                sys.exit("Error - unable to select input file")

    crop_rows(in_path)


    delete_Apps(in_path)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "output of `crop_rows`"? What kind of output? The value the function returns (which is currently `None` by default)? The text printed to the screen? The data written to the `in_path` file when conf is "Y"? something else?

Comment: Yes, I would like to feed the data written to the in_path file when conf is "Y" back into the delete_Apps function... I guess I'm wondering what to set equal to a new variable so that I can feed this variable into delete_Apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change crop_rows into a generator function (see https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and use it in delete_Apps.

Comment: I was hoping I could just make a new variable, like new_in_path, then call delete_Apps(new_in_path)... but I don't understand what I would set = to new_in_path to make this work

Comment: As an alternative you can call delete_Apps from crop_rows, passing data as a parameter. That will avoid you to reopen the file, read it and close it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the .csv file separately
2. Change `crop_rows` so that it takes rows as input and returns the new data
3. Then change `delete_Apps` to take rows input and to return the modified data
4. Finally write the .csv file

You can then simply nest calls to the functions, like this:

```
def read_input_file(in_path):
    # use with not to worry about closing the file
    with open(in_path, 'rb') as file_obj:
        reader = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter='\t')
        return list(reader)

def crop_rows(input_rows):
    data = []
    for row in input_rows:
        if not row or not any(row):
            break #stop at empty row
        else:
            data.append(row)

    print 'Found', len(data), 'rows of data without empty lines.'
    conf = raw_input('delete remaining lines? (Y|N): ').upper()[0]

    if conf == 'Y':
        return data       
    else:
        # return unmodified data
        return input_rows

def delete_Apps(input_rows):
    data = []
    for row in input_rows:
        if 'Applicant' not in row:
            data.append(row)

    print 'Found', len(data), 'Leads with Applicant in gHire as Status.'
    conf = raw_input('delete these leads? (Y|N): ').upper()[0]

    if conf == 'Y':
        return data
    else:
        return input_rows

def write_output_file(data, out_path):
    wirg open(out_path, 'wb') as file_obj:
    writer = csv.writer(file_obj)
    writer.writerows(data)
    file_obj.close()
```

The final call:

```
file_path='/tmp/whatever.csv'
write_output_file(delete_Apps(crop_rows(read_input_file(file_path)), file_path)
```